# How come the derivative of $y = \tan(x + c)$ is $y' = 1 +\ tan^2(x + c)$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

[problem from homework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuvyH.png)

I got the correct answer, but I'm having trouble understanding the part where it says

> Differentiating $y = \tan(x + c)$ we get $y' = 1 + \tan^2(x + c)$

My understanding is that the derivative of $\tan(x + c)$ is $\sec^2(x + c)$. Why is this not the case here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1+\tan^2(x)=\sec^2(x)$, to see this start from $$\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1$$ then divide by $\cos^2(x)$.